# Practical applications for Java 8's Constructor references?

Tags: java, constructor, java-8, closures, method-reference

So I just spent 2 hours trying to find a practical example of Java 8's constructor references that actually makes sense to me. It's not that I don't understand the syntax or semantic of constructor references. But I can't come up with a use case where I could/would use them. The examples I found basically just introduced a pretty meaingless functional interface and a matching class/constructor just to be able to make use of the constructor reference. But what it came down to was just doing a simple `new...()` in a very complicated way. The functional interface was never used in any other way than via a constructor reference, so what's the point?

Can someone please give me a practical example where you could use a constructor reference for a functional interface implementation, but where the functional interface is not JUST used for passing this constructor reference, but actually has a reason to exist because it is used with other implementations as well?

Comment: The point of a constructor reference is to just pass the reference to the constructor. Similarly, the point of a method reference is to pass a reference to the method.  Are you expecting it to do something more?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Comment: Consider them as generators.

Comment: Look at the 3- and 4-arg versions of `Collectors.groupingBy()`, where you can specify a `Supplier` for the map.  You can specify a constructor ref like `TreeMap::new` for this.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of a non-trivial constructor reference

```
private final Map<String, BigInteger> biCache = new HashMap<>();

public BigInteger parse(String str) {
    return biCache.computeIfAbsent(str, BigInteger::new);
}
```

In this case

```
BigInteger::new
```

is actually similar to

```
s -> new BigInteger(s)
```